# Access JSON element in array by key

Tags: javascript, json

I have following JSON structure

```
myObj = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30,
  cars: [{ type: "car", year: "1998" }, { type: "van", year: "1995" }]
};
```

I need to get the year of the car where thepseudois = car

In pesudo code

```
myObj.cars.getElement(type=car).year
```

which should give me 1998 as the output.

Can I do this in Javascript without loops

I need to get the year of the car where the type is = car

In pesudo code

```
myObj.cars.getElement(type=car).year
```

which should give me 1998 as the output.

Can I do this in Javascript without loops

Comment: Just fetch the entire array like `myObj.cars` and then use `.filter` to fetch the relevant nested objects inside the array

Comment: "I have following JSON structure" — That is JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: myObj.cars.find(o => o.type === "car").year , for your question this will work. Since find returns the first object that satisfies the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `map()`:

```js
let myObj ={
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars":[ {"type":"car", "year":"1998"}, 
           {"type":"van", "year":"1995"}]
};

var carYear = myObj.cars.filter(c => c.type=='car').map(y=>y.year);
console.log(carYear);
```

Comment: myObj.cars.find(o => o.type === "car").year , for the above question this will work. Since find returns the first object that satisfies the condition. Its a suggestion.